# Unable to find package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to get swagger libraries but following error occurs, even when a new project I created comes with a by default error:

`dotnet add package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore --version 2.0.0`

```
Writing C:\Users\shubham.shaw\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpoxoxul.tmp
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET for code signing.
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET for timestamping.
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore' into project 'C:\Users\shubham.shaw\source\repos\JWTImplementation\JWTImplementation.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for C:\Users\shubham.shaw\source\repos\JWTImplementation\JWTImplementation.csproj...
info :   GET https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
info :   GET https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Swashbuckle.AspNetCore'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Swashbuckle.AspNetCore'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
log  : No such host is known. (packagesource:443)
log  :   No such host is known.
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
log  : No such host is known. (packagesource:443)
log  :   No such host is known.
info :   GET https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
info :   GET https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Swashbuckle.AspNetCore'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
log  : No such host is known. (packagesource:443)
log  :   No such host is known.
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Swashbuckle.AspNetCore'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
log  : No such host is known. (packagesource:443)
log  :   No such host is known.
info :   GET https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
info :   GET https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Swashbuckle.AspNetCore'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
error: NU1301: Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets' from remote source 'https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
info : Package 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project 'C:\Users\shubham.shaw\source\repos\JWTImplementation\JWTImplementation.csproj'.
error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'version')


Usage: NuGet.CommandLine.XPlat.dll package add [options]

Options:
-h|--help               Show help information
--force-english-output  Forces the application to run using an invariant, English-based culture.
--package               Id of the package to be added.
--version               Version of the package to be added.
-d|--dg-file            Path to the dependency graph file to be used to restore preview and compatibility check.
-p|--project            Path to the project file.
-f|--framework          Frameworks for which the package reference should be added.
-n|--no-restore         Do not perform restore preview and compatibility check. The added package reference will be unconditional.
-s|--source             Specifies NuGet package sources to use during the restore.
--package-directory     Directory to restore packages in.
--interactive           Allow the command to block and require manual action for operations like authentication.
--prerelease            Allows prerelease packages to be installed.
```

I tried to check the configuration for package sources but nothing to observe for some issue.

Comment: How did you try to added the package ? Through visual studio or dotnet command ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic I tried both of the options, and the problem is that newly created projects are also giving this error, where Swashbukle is added by default for dependencies.

Comment: Is your project .net core ?

Comment: yes, below is the csproj configuration details, both PackageReference is showing the error:
`
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>sample</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message I can see that nugget restore is trying to restore your packages from : `GET https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?`

So my guess is that your package sources are not right. When you run this cmd command : `dotnet nuget list source` you should see `nuget.org` with address :
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json, if that is not the case the you should add NuGet as package source :

```
dotnet nuget add source  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --name nuget.org
```

then try and restore your packages.

Comment: Thanks for the resolution, It was interesting exploring the issue. Thank you for  the insight.